# PHP not getting variables from db to dashboard

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code; the idea is for a user to log in and be redirected to a dashboard which shows information such as username, registration date, e-mail. So php code is needed to pass variables from the database. However I get this dashboard:

[image: Dashboard no variables]

Here is the dashboard php:

```
    <?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit();
}

// Set up database connection
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "login_system";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Get user information from database
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
var_dump($result);
die;
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $_SESSION["email"] = $row["email"];
  $_SESSION["registration_date"] = $row["registration_date"];
}

mysqli_close($conn);

// Load dashboard html
include "dashboard.html";
?>
```

And over here the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>User Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></h1>
    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h2>Your Account</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Username:</strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION["email"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Registration Date:</strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION["registration_date"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone give me a hand on what's wrong?

Comment: What does your var_dump show?

Comment: nothing, I thought I could see that on the browser, but just blank...

Comment: Might be because you're including a `.html` file, try changing your dashboard to a `.php` file so that the variables can be accessed.

Comment: Are you saying absolutely nothing at all shows on the var_dump? If so it sounds as though you are not calling it at all. And what is the die immediately following it?

Comment: but the html file is separate, sorry I did not get what you meant

Comment: The die at the end was just a test, it returns nothing without it, can't seem to get why

Comment: So `include "dashboard.html";` does **not** bring in the code where you say “And over here the html”? Just to be clear. Also, `mysqli_query` returns either a `mysqli_result` or a bool, so _something_ should be dumped. If not, make sure full error reporting is enabled

Comment: dsahboard.html contains the webpage where the user lands when logged in

Comment: @MatíasHuartamendía rename `dashboard.html` to `dashboard.php` so that the PHP actually executes..

Comment: have you tried var_dump on $row ?

Comment: @Darren if I do that I'd have two dashboard.php files, what do I do with the code in the other?